# How to set "unseen" on emails - PHP

Tags: php, email, status, flags

I'm trying to make a program that takes e-mails from the post.
Everything is nice, beautiful. Almost..
Unfortunately, the problem is when the mail is "unseen". The script changes its status to "seen".

And I don't want this.

I tried to do that: at the beginning I check that emails are unseen, and at the end I'd like them to restore the status "unseen".
However, I met only with "imap_setflag_full" and it doesn't have that option.

```
    public function pop_mails(){
    $message_count = imap_num_msg($this -> _inbox);
    $date = date('Y-m-d'); 
    mkdir("./$date", 0777);

    for($i=1; $i<=$message_count; $i++){
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($this->_inbox, $i);

            $seen = $overview[0] -> seen;
            $name = imap_utf8($overview[0]->subject);
            $named = strtr($name, ":", ".");
            $headers = imap_fetchheader($this->_inbox, $i, FT_PREFETCHTEXT);

            $body = imap_body($this->_inbox, $i);
            file_put_contents($date.'/'.$named. '.eml', $headers . "\n" . $body);

            if($seen =="0") {
                imap_setflag_full($this->_inbox, $seen, "\\Seen");
            }   
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You're right. `FT_PEEK` is good way :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to clear the \\Seen Flag at the end of your process :

> $status = imap_clearflag_full($this->_inbox, "$email_number", " \\Seen");